# JQuery: can't get the correct identifier on click

Tags: jquery

Can't seem to get the `<i>` identifier properly so I can remove/add classes to it.  This is what I have, but it is not working to change the classes of `<i>`.  Pay no attention to the array and other stuff as that is working properly.

**js:**

```
$('#datatable').on('click', 'tr td:first-child', function () {

    // add/remove checked, active class, and id from array 
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');

    if ( $.inArray(id, selected) !== -1 )
    {
        $(this+ ' i').removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square');
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass("active");
        //add to array
        selected.push( id );
    }
    else {
        $(this+ ' i').removeClass('fa-check-square').addClass('fa-square-o');
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("active");
        //remove from array
        selected.splice($.inArray(id, selected),1);
    }
    //update count
    $("#dtCount").html(selected.length);
});
```

**html:**

```
<table id="datatable">
<tr id="dtrow_1" class="odd">
    <td class=" center">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o dt-checkboxes"></i>
    </td>
    .......
```

**EDIT:**

Everyone seems to be giving the same answer, but this does not do anything...

```
if ( $.inArray(id, selected) !== -1 )
{
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square');
    $(this).parents('tr').addClass('active');
    //add to array
    selected.push( id );
}
else {
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-check-square').addClass('fa-square-o')
    $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('active');
    //remove from array
    selected.splice($.inArray(id, selected),1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the `i` element which is a descendant of the current `td` so

change

```
$(this+ ' i')
```

to

```
$(this).find('i');// or $('i', this)
```

Your selector `$(this+ ' i')`, executes like `[object HTMLDivElement] i` because `this` is a dom element reference

---

```
var selected = []
$('#datatable').on('click', 'tr td:first-child', function () {

    // add/remove checked, active class, and id from array 
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');

    //this condition is wrong
    if ($.inArray(id, selected) === -1) {
        $(this).find(' i').removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square');
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass("active");
        //add to array
        selected.push(id);
    } else {
        $(this).find(' i').removeClass('fa-check-square').addClass('fa-square-o');
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("active");
        //remove from array
        selected.splice($.inArray(id, selected), 1);
    }
    //update count
    $("#dtCount").html(selected.length);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yfbM7/)

Comment: While there are no errors using find it is not removing or adding the classes. The 'i' stays exactly as it was.

Comment: @user756659 there is another problem in your condition, try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yfbM7/3/

Comment: Ahhh... thanks... I overlooked that as it was a copy/paste job from another part of my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `i` tag is descendant of current td (the event source). You can use 
[jQuery( selector [, context ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) or [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Change

```
$(this+ ' i').removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square');
```

To

```
$('i', this).removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square');
```

Or

```
$(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find`

```
$('#datatable').on('click', 'tr td:first-child', function () {

    // add/remove checked, active class, and id from array 
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');

    if ( $.inArray(id, selected) !== -1 )
    {
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square');
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass("active");
        //add to array
        selected.push( id );
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-check-square').addClass('fa-square-o');
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("active");
        //remove from array
        selected.splice($.inArray(id, selected),1);
    }
    //update count
    $("#dtCount").html(selected.length);
});
```

For more information on `.find()`, see [this](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct solution. Instead of trying to add a string to a html object you should first convert html object into a jQuery object & then look for the "i" tag inside of it.

```
$('#datatable').on('click', 'tr td:first-child', function () {

    // add/remove checked, active class, and id from array 
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');

    if ( $.inArray(id, selected) !== -1 )
    {
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square');
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass("active");
        //add to array
        selected.push( id );
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-check-square').addClass('fa-square-o');
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("active");
        //remove from array
        selected.splice($.inArray(id, selected),1);
    }
    //update count
    $("#dtCount").html(selected.length);
});
```